# HMS Core Playstore Version Cannot use Huawei ID Sign In

Tags: flutter, account, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

Firstly, I made an app with flutter, I just implement Account Kit and Scan Kit for the app. Well, I got a previous bug for using google pixel 3XL (AVD) API Level 30, then I tried to change it to Nexus 6 API Level 28, and it worked (the latest version of HMS Core on both AVD). After I tried to run the application on my phone(Poco F1, using HMS Core Playstore Version), I found a bug like the following picture

[image: The error message is obtained from the try-catch when calling the Account kit API, Error code is just random number]

But when I use the latest version of HMS Core, the bug is gone. Well, the problem it's not that much but when I submit the app to HMS Gallery, the reviewer found the bug and rejected my application proposal because he found an error message like the picture above, even though I already gave a note to use the latest HMS Core. But I don't think he read my note and it's like he doesn't understand the language(Indonesia) used in my application so he takes issue with the system that we have made, even though the application system that we made is like that.

.

Error Log - Huawei Sign In (Playstore Version HMS Core):

https://ghostbin.com/paste/wEqL4

.

note for reviewer:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/4ok59

.

attachment from reviewer:

https://obs.cn-north-2.myhuaweicloud.cn/nsp-appgallery-agcpri-drcn/application/errorFile/aff0e965b82548b2b7d180fc6cf31594.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=MPXW6JOQOEGGIVNZK2PN%2F20210803%2Fcn-north-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210803T162548Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=5dddb41e3a17cca9b50db3a8e55e14602e0035d9cfe3a58d6c7916ace344df76

.

Comment from the reviewer:

[Description]: An error occurs in your App). Please see the attachment， here is the path: Go to Console > App Service > AppGallery Connect>Find your app from the list and click the version to check the attachment. Please refer to rule 3.1 of "AppGallery Review Guidelines": https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/50104 ­[Test Step]: 1. When clicking on "Sign in with Huawei ID", an error message pops up. 2. When login in using the admin test account, a QR code appears and prompts "scan me", but there is no scanning function. [Test Environment]: Wi-Fi connection, EMUI 10.1.0 (Mate 30), EMUI10.0.0（P20 pro） Multilingual settings. ­[Suggestion]: Please identify it accordingly. Then revise and resubmit your app for review.

.

I've made a demo video for this threat, please check this

https://youtu.be/fPJgaHQTXoY

App:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KPJrmjGTWRGHNecqDI1Hs6-zuDJflBw3?usp=sharing

Please help me how can I submit this app

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

In the pics that you provided, we found a configuration issue.
`SigningConfigs` can contain `debug` or `release`.

so you can try to change here

[image]

to

[image]

---

In the screen recording that you provided, Error code `6003` is displayed.

[image]

To solve your issue, You need to check whether the certificate fingerprint of the APK signature file submitted to the AppGallery is the same as that configured on the AppGallery Connect website:

Ensure that the device and cloud configurations of the certificate fingerprint are consistent. The certificate packaged by the client application is the same as the SHA256 certificate fingerprint configured for the application on the AppGallery Connect website.

1. Verify that the certificate fingerprint is correctly configured when you apply for related services. Open the APK file of an app, extract the **META-INF** directory from the file, obtain the **CERT.RSA** file in the directory, and run the **keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA** command to record the signing certificate information.
2. Sign in to AppGallery Connect, click **My projects**, and select a required project. On the displayed page, select the app, go to **Project settings > General information**, and check whether the value in **SHA-256 certificate fingerprint** is the same as that in step 1.

In addition, HMS Core (APK) will cache the signature file. You need to find HMS Core (APK) on the Apps page of your device and clear its cache, restart your app, and perform the previous operation again.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, can you explain more fully how to check the CERT.RSA file in the APK file, because for the SHA-256 key problem I just signed in config on build.gradle, key properties, and I put the key file together with build.gradle app level
--------------------------------------------------------
sign in config: https://pasteboard.co/KgjGuMy.png
------------------------------------------------------
File structure: https://pasteboard.co/KgjGYkv9.png
------------------------------------------------------
key properties: https://pasteboard.co/KgjHOvT.png

Comment: hi@Theo, i just updated my answer, pls kindly refer that.